# Python Shape function for k-means clustering

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, geotiff

I have one geotiff grey scale image which gave me the (4377, 6172) 2D array. In the first part, I am considering (:1024, :1024) values(Total values are -> 1024 * 1024 = 1048576) for my compression algorithm. Through this algorithm, I am getting total 4 values in finalmatrix list var through the algorithm. After this, I am applying K-means algorithm on that values. A program is below :

```html
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
from sklearn import cluster
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset =gdal.Open("1.tif")
band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
img = band.ReadAsArray()

finalmat = [255, 0, 2, 2]

#Converting list to array for dimensional change
ay = np.asarray(finalmat).reshape(-1,1)    

fig = plt.figure()

k_means = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=2)
k_means.fit(ay)

cluster_means = k_means.cluster_centers_.squeeze()
a_clustered = k_means.labels_

print('# of observation :',ay.shape)

print('Cluster Means : ', cluster_means)

a_clustered.shape= img.shape

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(125,125))

ax = plt.subplot(2,4,8)
plt.axis('off')
xlabel = str(1) , ' clusters'
ax.set_title(xlabel)
plt.imshow(a_clustered)
    
plt.show()
fig.savefig('kmeans-1 clust ndvi08jan2010_guj 12 .png')
```

In the above Program I am getting error in the line  **a_clustered.shape= img.shape**. The error which I am getting is below:

```html
Error line:  

a_clustered.shape= img.shape

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4 into shape (4377,6172)

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x7fb7c63975c0>
```

Actually, I want to visualize the clustering on Original image through compressed value which I am getting. Can you please give suggestion what to do

Answer (score 0):

It does not make a lot of sense to use KMeans on 1 dimensional data.

And it makes even less sense to use it on a 4 x 1 array!

Your site then comes from the fact that you can't just resize a 4 x 1 integer array into a large picture.

Just print the array `a_clustered` you are trying to plot. It probably contains `[0, 1, 1, 1]`.